# Android Ndk DuplicateFileException

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have this error while running application in android studio. It builds project successfully but gives this error when I run it.Does anyone have solution.

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':ftrScanDemoUsbHost:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate filescopied in APK lib/armeabi/libftrScanAPI.so     
  File1: 
    E:\FtrScanDemoUsbHost\ftrScanDemoUsbHost\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\FtrScanDemoUsbHost\ftrWsqAndroidHelper\unspecified\jni
  File2:  
    E:\FtrScanDemoUsbHost\ftrScanDemoUsbHost\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\FtrScanDemoUsbHost\ftrScanApiAndroidHelperUsbHost\unspecified\jni
```

Comment: `DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi/libftrScanAPI.so` ... You have duplicate file

Comment: Duplication in dependencies

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I've found to deal with this is to add the following section to your application's build.gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libftrScanAPI.so'
}
```